# rtvscan.exe uses too much memory about 250,416k

Tags: memory-usage

Symantec rtvscan.exe uses too much memory about 250,416k. Is there a way to reduce it?

Answer (score 1):

What version of the software are you using? Is it SAV or SEP?  Is it a managed client or stand alone?

This can be expected if a scan is running.  Does the usage stay this high all the time or just at certain times.

I have also seen an install issue that puts NavLogon.dll in an unexpected location. Also an issue with the registry entry if this happens  Not sure how but this has been reported to cause high CPU and RAM usage.

Can't find the exact aticle but this one also speaks to this somewhat. [RTVSCAN issues](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/rtvscanexe-high-memory-usage-sav)